# SOAP request to update record e.g. Customers In Quickbook Through WebConnector

Tags: web-services, soap, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am using **QuickBook Webconnector** to synchronize the data between QuickBook and Sugar CRM. I have been successfully implemented add and import functions through SOAP request on QuickBook But I have no idea about how to update QuickBook records through SOAP request. Please guide and help me to write SOAP request for update record e.g. to update customer in QuickBook through WebConnector.

I am using Webconnector API in PHP that is available on https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php.

**Is it possible to update customers data in Quickbook against their ListID?
If possible then any guidline about to update customers data against their ListID's**

**I want help related to update customer SOAP request like... below code of Add customer SOAP request.**

```
function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
// Grab the data from our MySQL database
$arr = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_customer_table WHERE id = " . (int) $ID));

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
    <QBXML>
        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                <CustomerAdd>
                    <Name>' . $arr['name'] . '</Name>
                    <CompanyName>' . $arr['name'] . '</CompanyName>
                    <FirstName>' . $arr['fname'] . '</FirstName>
                    <LastName>' . $arr['lname'] . '</LastName>
                </CustomerAdd>
            </CustomerAddRq>
        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
    </QBXML>';

return $xml;
}
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the QBWC Programmers Guide for integrating the SOAP and QBXML commands
https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/doc/PDF/QBWC_proguide.pdf